# Change of variables from characteristic to initial condition/Derivative of ODE solution with respect to initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable, characteristics

I am trying to emulate a change of variables performed in *A model of physiologically structured population dynamics with nonlinear individual growth rate* (Calsina, Saldaña) in Equation (8). The idea is they model a size-structured population with a PDE. They find a solution to a PDE using the Method of Characteristics, then integrate the solution with respect to the size-variable $x$ to compute the total population.

They define $x(t)=\varphi(t;x_0,t_0)$ to be the characteristic solution to the ODE:
$$x'(t)=\gamma(x(t),t)$$
$$x(t_0)=x_0$$

then make a change of variables in Equation (8) from $x \rightarrow \xi :=\varphi(0;x,t)$. They track the characteristic solution $\varphi$ that goes through the point $(x,t)$ back to the initial point $(\xi,0)$, but I am unsure how to find the partial derivative of $x$ with respect to $\xi$. My first attempt was to consider (where $x(t):=X(t,\xi)$):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} \left(\frac{\partial X(t,\xi)}{\partial t} \right) & = \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} \left( \gamma(X(t,\xi),t) \right) \\
& = \frac{\partial \, \gamma(X(t,\xi),t)}{\partial X} \, \frac{\partial X(t,\xi)}{\partial \xi}
\end{align}

but from here I am stuck. Please help with any insight you may have.

Comment: You can consider the derivatives for $s$ in $\phi(t;x_0,t_0)=\phi(t;\phi(t-s;x_0,t_0),t-s)$ at $s=0$.

Comment: Why $s=0$? Should it be $s=t-t_0$? Also I still am confused on how to differentiate $\phi(t;\phi(t-s;x_0,t_0),t-s)$ wrt $s$ using the chain rule.

Comment: I am at the point:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \, \phi(t;\phi(t-s;x_0,t_0),t-s)}{\partial s} & = -\phi^{(0,1,0)}(t;\phi(t-s;x_0,t_0),t-s)\, \phi^{(1,0,0)}(t-s;x_0,t_0) - \phi^{(0,0,1)}(t;\phi(t-s;x_0,t_0),t-s) \\
& = -\phi^{(0,1,0)}(t;\phi(t-s;x_0,t_0),t-s) \gamma(\phi(t-s;x_0,t_0),t-s) - \phi^{(0,0,1)}(t;\phi(t-s;x_0,t_0),t-s)
\end{align}
does this seem right?

Comment: The composition formula can be differentiated and evaluated in many ways, but I think what is discussed above is the most useful variant. Try out the variants of setting $s$.